# mod_rewrite for any query containing a certain string

Tags: apache, parsing, redirect, mod-rewrite

Running Apache 2.2.xx on multiple older boxes - quite often get connctions which are clearly intended to be looking for WordPress (say), or any other of a number of CMS which may or may not be security risks (I have no CMS actually, on these systems, but that's besides the point).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to autmatically parse the query for a diagnistoic bit -- such as

/setup/wp

/wp-config/setup.script

And so on. Both contain 'wp', and are pretty clear attempts to find a WordPress install. I'm hoping to autnmitally redirect them to either an error page (say, 404), or something else (ideally, I'd love to write out their ip address, so I could do a permanent ban on them at some point, but for now, a simple redirect would suffice.

I've got a bit of a handle on ho mod_redirect works, but can't suss out how to take the basic idea, and make it work if the query string contains a target element anywhere in the string? I know how to get (say) perl to parse a string for a word, or the like, but haven't stumbled across the equivalent for mod_rewrite (which I would then embed in my httpd.conf).

Points to an example of 'how to do this' most appreciated.

And, preemptively:

1\ yes, I know that could simply ignroe them, since the pages being looked for don't exist
2\ there is an eement of 'danger' in  automatically redirecting a search string that contains a certain substring, if that substring shows up for some legitamate pages.

At this point, I'm simply looking to see how it would be done, leaving decisions on whether (or not) it should be done to later.

Comment: Banning IP addresses does not make any sense, those are distributed attacks.

Comment: Take a look at the `fail2ban` package which allows to do exactly what you want. It is able to scan new entries in the access log file and trigger a configurable action. That will not block the request t hand, indeed, but as you said yourself: those requests do not pose a thread anyway.

Comment: If however you really want to slow down your http server by means of rewriting those requests, then sure, it is certainly possible to implement a `RewriteRule` for such patterns. I suggest you simply take a look into the documentation of apache's rewrite module. it is of excellent quality and comes with good examples.